# jQuery Accordion Menu Animation Wobble

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-ui-accordion

I've built a simple jQuery animated accordion menu using the slideUp and slideDown functions (also tried it with slideToggle) and while it looks great it the animation is perfectly smooth even though all accordion menu elements are the same height. As you can see, [even here on jQueryUIs example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/), when you click an element, the bottom of the menu rises a little bit and then settles back after the animation completes. I assume this has to do with a slight timing difference in the animations but even setting a delay doesn't fix the issue. Anyone know I way to smooth out this issue? It's important since the site I'm working on is essentially one giant accordion menu so the issue becomes very noticeable.

Answer (score 2):

My 2c:

I assume that you want to avoid the jittery below the accordion where the entire page shuffles down and up. Am I in the right path? If so, I would study the behaviour and adjust the holding div to a fixed height giving it either 1, 2, 3 extra px on the bottom.

I too have noticed that "problem" in my applications in general.

Comment: Seems to be common in many jQuery animations like this. I fear that even with the holding div a constant height the headers themselves will still wobble a bit. Seems to be fairly browser/compter specific since I believe it's caused by the slight delay between the two animations: sliding up and sliding down (though it happens with toggle too so I assume toggle uses a similar method internally).